# Can typescript define uncallable method in a class?

Tags: typescript

I want the type checker to report an error when the user call the uncallable method.

For example:

```js
interface Box{
  open(): Box;
  close(): Box;
}

class CloseBox implements Box{
  open(){
    return new OpenBox();
  }
  close(): never{
    throw "No I should not call this method"
  }
}

class OpenBox implements Box{
  open(): never{
    throw "No I should not call this method"
  }
  close(): CloseBox{
    return new CloseBox();
  }
}

new OpenBox().open() // I want the type checker to report an error.
```

As we know, A opened box should not open again. How can I define the open method?

Comment: Why does Box expose the `open` method, as opposed to ClosedBox or OpenableBox? You're defeating the type checker by saying that there's a callable method you shouldn't call. This will be particularly nefarious if you have a variable `b: Box` that you call `open` on, if you've assigned an OpenBox to `b`.

Comment: @JeffBowmansupportsMonica I know the risk but in my enviroment supposed the situation will not occur.

Comment: And if the situation occur, just report an Runtime Execption will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `never`, which works because `never` is [considered a subtype of all types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never), and you are allowed to return a subtype from a subclass or subinterface. Typescript won't throw an error associated with your call to `open`, but it will recognize that the call to `open` will not return normally, which is true: You can call `open` without fear of calling an `undefined` method, but it will absolutely throw a runtime exception as you described in the comments.

Note that this is a feature [introduced in Typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions), so you must be running Typescript 3.7 or later to see the error.

```js
interface Box {
  open(): OpenBox;
}

interface OpenBox extends Box {
  open(): never;
}

interface ClosedBox extends Box {
  // Open the box like usual.
}

function methodOne(closedBox: ClosedBox) {
  closedBox.open();  // This is guaranteed safe.
  return 42;         // No worries here.
}

function methodTwo(openBox: OpenBox) {
  openBox.open();    // This is guaranteed to throw.
  return 9001;       // Typescript gives #7027: Unreachable code detected.
}

function methodThree(box: Box) {
  box.open();        // This code is ambiguous.
  return 8675309;    // It will throw at runtime if you pass an OpenBox.
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeAoZZdABwhAAoBKALmQHlSQNMBuPAXzz1ElkRQZlmyCJkggAJgGc0WXASKMqtEBABu0Np27ho8JMgDCAG3RSIE4aPHTZ2fIQD0j+o2RgAFigBGc48ABrFABXKWC4YwA6Di4YYJAEMGB0EGQAWwhPdAk6VXIEU3NLLFoTMwtmSnlCAvLizEiSMioWJxcAFQ9gGW7kAHNwqDhdC2QpOBgIaMIoTOCoVIAWACZWwnX152QAOXRkAHd0KChgCBkvWejtOISklPTMj2z2w-ImphLXISwqh0VvhrvFobLadXq9AZwIYjCTuPaeKDofbTZCzMDzVIATgADNiAIxrDbIUEAT1IUgQJ2IYH6wA0MgAxAB2bHLJm0ACqIFmiA8cG8xhQCGyKAkmQgiQsV1i8USyVSGSyEk6swg5F8mFolWqyA1jSUlEJRNBXRkwrFyF6cDS3mAA3QoRRaIxyAAHAA2JkAVgAzNjMUatgBJGn7YDGYzuDyI-bIOA0qDxJIZS0wZAkh3IYhwKQyYZfD4NGJAA)

As I wrote in the comments, you are still defeating the type checker by indicating to Typescript that it is safe to call `open` on any Box, including OpenBox and ClosedBox, but expressing at runtime that you cannot `open` an OpenBox. For better compile-time safety, you can define the `open` method on ClosedBox instead of Box, forcing the user to check that the box is closed before even trying to call `open` on it.

You could make this particularly easy with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), where you can tell Typescript that the type `is ClosedBox`.

```js
interface Box {
  isClosed(): this is ClosedBox;
}

interface OpenBox extends Box {}

interface ClosedBox extends Box {
  open(): OpenBox;
}

function methodOne(closedBox: ClosedBox) {
  closedBox.open();  // This is guaranteed safe.
  return 42;         // No worries here.
}

function methodTwo(openBox: OpenBox) {
  openBox.open();    // Error 2339: property 'open does not exist on 'OpenBox'.
}

function methodThree(box: Box) {
  if (box.isClosed()) {
    box.open();      // No cast needed: Typescript knows Box is ClosedBox,
                     // so it must have an 'open' method.
  }
  return 8675309;
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeAoZZYAZwGEAbdYiAEwAoBKALmTAAsSjjkKraNMAbjwBfPHlCRYiFAHkADhBADkETJBA1uKnGInho8JD0rUaKtRq1osuAsnSKQjFgqUDhemAFcQCMMDoIMgAthDs6DSyIBB0CKb8WCy8ZgIMdoTxfOZYAHSOSoyChAD0JcgAKhzcnADm3nBQcAa0yMRwMBC59lDh3lDBACwATMWE4+NlyABy6MgA7uhQUMAQ3GzQXaLiPn4BQaHhbJEVi3QFyknIbpeY6fiEFwL5TkUTUwCiy0vIwwDMfwAnCx5FAClAwABPZAAcguyBo6DWyBA6DAqkwJHRBxhNwEMO6Xl8-kCwTCERoVV6sQARlc0hkiDBkHQ6ZhciQUrRGPd7IQ2S9Cgwxu9yrNkAg4MR0TFaLQWBVIYpiAgVvJ0QBrVHzbS2ThcnKYAA0fImZvNk3KxDmwHRIW80uQbDgADcUM1YRcYYcKd1CGJCL0wP1ggAOABsAHYAKx-AAMgM8QA)

Comment: The only thing I knew is typescript do not support static check for calling never function, I push the issue and they told me there is a design limit.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `Box` require an `open` method to be present?

Instead of:

```
interface Box {
   name: string;
   open: () => OpenBox;
}
```

Why not do the following:

```
interface Box {
  name: string;
}

interface ClosedBox extends Box {
  open: () => OpenBox;
}
```